pytest - collect information about test together with parameters
I am using pytest. I would like to query the framework to get a list of all the tests that would be scheduled to run, together with the parameters for each test.
By query, I mean an action to acquire that info.
When I execute pytest -s --co, I get some info but not all the info. The issue is that I want to be able to get the explicit parameters used in each test, not a label like pytest_parameters0.
<Module test_name.py>
<Function test_do[pytest_parameters0]
<Function test_do[pytest_parameters1]

I have also tried to implement hook functions like "pytest_collection_modify_items", however I a have not been able to retrieve the parameter information by this means either. Is there a way to do what I am seeking?
Any help will be appreciated!

Implement a pytest_collection hook is a viable solution. You can enumerate test items via session.items, and access parameters of each test item via keywords.
def pytest_collection_finish(session: pytest.Session):
    for item in session.items:
        print(f"Test item: {item.nodeid}")
        for k, v in item.keywords.items():
            print(f"  {k}: {v}")


Thanks @liuyu. I will give this a try. Will that hook run without executing the tests, i.e. --collect-only ?

@stackQA yes, this pytest_collection_finish hook is invoked as the 3rd step of the collection phase (i.e., --collect-only), documented here https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/reference/reference.html#pytest.hookspec.pytest_collection
